# How do I compute the degree of this function?

Tags: continuity

I have the following problem:

> Let $f,g:S^1\rightarrow S^1$ be continuous mags with degree $\deg(f), \deg(g)$. Compute the degree of $g\circ f$

I first denoted $\deg(f)=n$ and $\deg(g)=m$. Then I know that f and g are homotopic to $z\mapsto z^{n,m}$ restricted to the unit circle. But I somehow don't see how to procede. Could someone help me?
This would be very nice

Thank you a lot

Comment: Homotopy commutes with composition and preserves degree so $g\circ f \cong (z\mapsto  z^m) \circ (z\mapsto z^n )=  z\mapsto (z^n )^m =  z\mapsto  z^{m*n}$ which is of degree $m*n$

Comment: sorry but we haven't shown all this things isn't there another possibility

Comment: I think I quite got it, the only point I don't see yet is why Homotopy preserves degree. could you maybe explain this to me

Comment: You can lift a map $f:S^{1}\rightarrow S^1$ to a map $\bar{f}:S^{1}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\bar{f}(x+1) - \bar{f}(x)$ is constant and corresponds to the degree of $f$. Applying  this trough a homotopy we see that the degree of $f_{y}$ is $d(y) = \bar{f}_{y}(1) - \bar{f}_{y}(0)$ where  $y\in[0,1]$ is the homotopy parameter. As a function of $y$ and difference of $\bar{f}_y$ this is continuous, but also only takes values in $\mathbb{Z}$, due to being a degree,  so it is constant.

Comment: Tough I'm guessing you still need to  show you can extend a lift throughout a homotopy. The exact statement is "the degree of a map  is homotopy invariant", but I haven't been able to find a reference to a proof.

Comment: Informally speaking, you can stretch and move a rubber band around an infinite cylinder (homotopy) ,  but you can't change the number the times it's wrapped around (degree).

Comment: ah okey this makes sense with the rubber band. thank you